# Saving check box selection without POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Lets say you have the the following code in your view

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDs" value="@x.ID"  /> 
}
```

The user then makes bunch of selections clicks some link. How do pass the the ids of the selected check boxes to the controller.

e.g you have the following link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "ActionName", new { selection = ???? // i dont know how i reference the checke boxes })
```

I know I can put the loop in a Html begin form and make the link a submit button but this is an abstract of the problem i am trying to solve. In the actual application i cannot convert the link to button.

**I would prefer not to use JavaScript if possible.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know that there is a way to do this with typical MVC helpers. What I have done in the past is created the link so that it's onclick called a custom jquery function that would select all of the inputs with type checkbox who are selected, and then create a list to be sent back.

Something like this:

```
$(
    $('#anchorid').click(function()
        {
            SubmitCheckBoxes();
        });
);

function SubmitCheckBoxes()
{
    var list = {};
    $(input[type="checkbox"]:checked).each(
        function() 
        {
            var identifier = $(this).attr('for');
            if(identifier == undefined)
                identifier = $(this).attr('name');
            if(list[identifier])
                list[identifier].push($(this).val());
            else
                list[identifier] = [$(this).val()];
        });
    //This must be here to make any json array not have brackets.
    //MVC binding will not work otherwise
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    $.post("./ActionName", list, function(data){//do something on response});
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without using JavaScript ?

Comment: Not that I know of, in fact there is a lot that is done via JavaScript/JQuery in MVC. It is just autogenerated for you. If you do not want to do this within a form, then javascript is really the only way I know of.

Comment: I see :(. well thanks for the answer anyways i might just have to do it this way

Comment: No problem, I always like to remind newcomers to SO that the primary means of appreciation is through upvotes (once you have enough points) and accepting answers (checkmark next to answer). If you have any other questions, the [FAQ] is a great resource, especially the [ASK]

Answer (score 0):

You could easily store the selected checkboxes' values in an array while ticking/unticking them.
i.e.

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var values = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      values[i] = $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```

and at the point that you are ready, you could either hook onto your link and do a straight forward post and pass the "values" as your parameters to the jquery post method.

Comment: is there any way to do this without using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

To submit the data to the controller without using JavaScript you need to use an HTML form submission. There are a lot of options such as buttons, inputs of type submit or inputs of type image within your form. You could use the image to give the appearance of a link but this may not be ideal.

If you cannot use buttons or inputs of submit/image then JavaScript is probably your next best option.

Any reason you cannot use buttons or JavaScript?